# How to catch SqlIntegrityConstraint violation exception

Tags: oracle, exception, unique-constraint, sqlexception, ojdbc

I have a scenario where user submits an order for a fund and a security. And if he submits the another order with same fund and security DB throws back `SqlIntegrityVoilationException` with error code `ora-00001`.

But my question here is this exception is not getting caught under `java.sql.sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception`. I am able to catch this under `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`, but I am not able to retrieve the error code (to check for `ora-00001`).

Anybody has any ideas how to catch that exception and retrieve the error code to check so that I can put back a custom error message like "you cannot submit a dup order for same fund and security combination".

## EDIT

```
catch (SQLException e) {
      ex = e; inOrder.setActionMessage(ex.getMessage()); 
}
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
      ex = e; inOrder.setActionMessage(ex.getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: PLEASE show your relevant code.

Comment: catch (SQLException e) {
                    ex = e;
                    inOrder.setActionMessage(ex.getMessage());
                } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
                    ex = e;
                   
                    inOrder.setActionMessage(ex.getMessage());
                }

Comment: Don't use comments to include additional information as it's very likely to be overlooked (I know I missed it at first). Instead, use the `edit` button (just below the tags) to edit the text of the question. I've done it for you this time but you might want to go in and format the code to your liking. Thanks.

Comment: Comment out your existing catches, and replace with catch( Exception e), then set a breakpoint, and see what actual type e is referencing.  Did you also look at the stack trace?

Comment: The problem is I can catch that exception in DataIntegrityViolationException. This cannot be caught in SQLException too. I can catch in Exception but I cannot check for the errorcode. as its a SQLException I want to check for the errorcode. something like e.getSQLException().getErrorCode()